# Period wildcard not working in Bash pattern replacement

Tags: regex, bash

Given this Bash code:

```
TEMP="1_2"
echo ${TEMP/_.*/}
```

why does it print out `1_2` instead of `1`?

I've also tried these, but they don't work:

```
echo ${TEMP/_\.*/}
echo ${TEMP/_\\.*/}
```

This does work:

```
echo ${TEMP/_[0-9]*/}
```

but I want to know:

1. Why isn't the period acting as a wildcard?
2. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A question mark is the single-character wildcard. However, it doesn't work like regular expressions where the asterisk is a quantifier. In Bash, in parameter expansions, an asterisk is a multicharacter wildcard.

```
$ temp=1_2
$ echo "${temp/_*}"
1
```

The following also work in this particular situation. See [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbBB) in `man bash` for more information regarding the differences.

```
echo "${temp%_*}"
echo "${temp%%_*}"
```

I recommend against using all-caps variable names in order to reduce the chance of name collision with shell or environment variables.

Comment: I see, it's using file-globbing, not regexes.  Confusing.

Comment: @AdamCrume: Well, it's *globbing*, but I wouldn't call it "file globbing".

Comment: Note that Bash can also support regular expressions, inside [[ ... ]] using the =~ match operator.